# Exchange Web Services: Access proposed date and time through Appointment

Tags: exchangewebservices

When a meeting invitee proposes a new meeting time, in outlook this information can be found in the "Scheduling Assistant" (outlook 2007):

[image]

Is there any way to access this information programmatically through the EWS API? The RequiredAttendees and OptionalAttendees collections of the [Appointment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.appointment_members%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) allow me to find out whether and when the attendee has responded, but how can one access the actual proposed new time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get this information using the EWS from the Appointment, I'm afraid. It's part of the PR_MESSAGE_RECIPIENTS property, which is a MAPI table (or Object, if you will), and EWS does not support retrieving this. Technically, you could probably get it if you want to build out the ExportItem functionality (a supported function serverside that is not built into the EWS Managed API) and pick through a massive binary stream to find the information, but that's hardly feasible. I haven't tried it myself. The other alternative would be to use something other than EWS to access the data.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tried this before but here is how I think you'd go about getting this information. The EWS service and the EWS Managed API don't have this implemented as first class functionality. To be more precise, the [propose new time functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495613%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) is currently available as first class functionality with Exchange Online. For Exchange Online, you will need to inspect the meeting response message XML for the ProposedStartTime and ProposedEndTime elements. So if you are using Exchange 2007, 2010, and currently 2013, you will need to do what I state in the next paragraph. You should be able to access this information by using extended properties.

An attendee that proposes a new meeting time will always result in the organizer getting a meeting message. When the organizer performs a GetItem request for the meeting message sent by an attendee, the request should request the [PR_RECIPIENT_PROPOSED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee179674%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx) property. A value of true indicates that the recipient proposed a new time. This should trigger a request to get the PR_RECIPIENT_PROPOSEDENDTIME and PR_RECIPIENT_PROPOSEDSTARTTIME property values.

Here is [an example of getting this type of property](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Exchange-2013-Access-a-719875ac) with the EWS Managed API;

Here is a quick property definition:

ExtendedPropertyDefinition PidTagRecipientProposed = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x5FE1, MapiPropertyType.Boolean);

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply. Getting this information through the meeting response I already tried and this works. However, I would specifically need to access the proposed time through the Appointment itself, because the meeting responses have been deleted.

Comment: The advice on extended properties is always good, but you cannot retrieve that property via EWS. It's buried in a RecipientRow in the PR_MESSAGE_RECIPIENTS table, and EWS cannot retrieve it. The same applies to extended properties for attachments. Anything in an Object/Table structure serverside cannot be retrieved with EWS unless that information is already baked into the API.

Comment: @Michael Mainer: Since the meeting message we are accessing using FindItem was made against an outlook meeting request, how can we grab the exchange meeting id from the meeting message itself?